# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$,for every $x\in[a,b]$, exists $y\in[a,b]$ such that $|f(x)|\leq\frac{1}{2}|f(y)|$, prove that $f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus

To prove that $f(x)=0$, I suppose one would have to prove that f is firstly a constant function and find a value $a$ such that $f(a)=0$--am I on the right track? Or, prove that $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)=0$ first? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Prove that there exists r st $|f(x)|<|f(r)|/2^n$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since $f(x)$ is continuous, so is $|f(x)|$ and it attains a maximal value on a compact interval.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose there is an $x\in[a,b]$ with $f(x)\neq 0$, then you have a $y\in [a,b]$ with $|f(y)|\geq 2|f(x)|$. What would happen if you continued this process? At some point you will need a theorem which is sometimes called 'the nameless theorem': A continuous function on a closed bounded interval is bounded and attains its bounds.